# Masking a plane

Tags: masking

I have a plane that should be masked similarly to what the person displays in this video with a torus: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wS-36yegLcg But when I apply all the masking rules as shown in the video my plane is not doing the same thing and is just displaying lines. I am a little new to blender and not sure whether this modifier works on a plane or not similar to the torus object.[image: masked plane]

Comment: have you subdivided your plane a bit?

Comment: No I didn't, but have just done it now and the transition did work! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plane doesn't have enough topology, it has only 4 vertices, the *Mask* modifier makes 2 of these vertices invisible and therefore your whole object invisible. The solution is to subdivide your plane, it will keep the weight gradient.